# android studio emulator running and working, but after some actions make invisible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttd8D.png)

My android studio emulator starts up and runs my app. However, after a few taps (completely random, but often it is a swipe up), it disappears and a message appears that the emulator is not running. Although in the avd manager it is shown as running. It does not allow you to delete or make a wipe date, because the emulator is running. Only restarting the studio helps.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem like this:

1. Deleted the emulator,
2. re-installed it and updated my system's video drivers.

In case if the above doesn't works, then you can use adb server shelltools:

1. To kill the adb server
   For Ubuntu Users:

```
sudo adb kill-server
```

For Windows users:

```
adb kill-server
```

2. To start server

```
sudo adb start-server
```

```
adb start-server
```